# Apex trigger error Invalid loop variable type expected

Tags: apex

Getting Invalid loop variable type expected Id was Transaction__c error in the last for loop. P.s. I am also using a trigger handler:

```
Set<Id> transactionIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(TransactionItem__c rec: (List<TransactionItem__c >) Trigger.new) {
            transactionIds.add(rec.Transaction__c);
        }

        Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
        SELECT Transaction__c Id, count(Id) sum
            FROM TransactionItem__c
            WHERE Transaction__c = :transactionIds
            GROUP BY Transaction__c
        ]);

        for(Transaction__c record: transactionIds) {
            Integer itemCount = (Integer)results.get(record.Id)?.get('sum');
                if(itemCount == null) {
                    itemCount = 0;
                }
            System.debug('Total transaction items = ' + itemCount);
        }
```

Comment: When you do `transactionIds.add(rec.Transaction__c)` you actually put an id into the list. So your `for` loop must be `for ( Id recordId : transactionIds) `

Comment: These are compilations error. Please go through how to write code in apex. Trailheads are good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger is working on TransactionItem__c, so that's what you need to use in your loop:

```
for(TransactionItem__c record: (TransactionItem__c[])Trigger.new) {
    Integer itemCount = (Integer)results.get(record.Transaction__c)?.get('sum');
        if(itemCount == null) {
            itemCount = 0;
        }
    System.debug('Total transaction items = ' + itemCount);
}
```

Comment: Finally it ran successfully! I know I need to do a lot of learning. I am doing so and I will get there with the help of Awesome people like you. Thanks @sfdcfox - appreciate all the help.